Continuous bits in NRZ DAC, causing synchronization issues
I am doing a 12-bit 100MS/s DAC in 40nm, I read some papers that are related to DAC from JSSC. A few papers show RZ encoding for better ISI and synchronization of bits. After reading a few papers i came to know that this RZ came into picture after knowing the issues of continuous bits in NRZ.
My question is "For a 12 bit DAC when do we get the synchronization problem ( for how many bits in sequence). Is synchronization related to single bit or all the 12 bits. If it is related to a single bit, how many bits can be in sequence so that i can avoid synchronization issues and ISI problems.
Edited : As there two types of encoding schemes in DAC. NRZ is used for high speed whereas RZ encoding is used for better sync and to reduce the ISI.
RZ is used over NRZ because NRZ has the disadvantages of same continuous bits which could effect the sync. I want to know for how many same continuous bits we get the sync problem in NRZ DAC.
Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why would you even output pure data without any encoding, framing or a clock signal?

we'll need more information on your DAC's data bus: I gather this is not just a parallel data bus with a separate clock signal, but some kind of self-clocking bus? (is that correct?) Then, is it a serial bus, or a parallel bus with self-clocked lanes? You should please edit your question to explain the data interface of your DAC in much more detail!
